# Does the AWS CloudFormation allowed pattern will allow # symbol in the email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We are using an # symbol for DL list in our company. For example, #test-emailcheck@example.com. Through AWS CloudFormation template we are validating the email address. But the example which I mentioned is not accepted by AWS. Below is my template which works for usual email id like test.emailcheck@example.com,

```
"contactemail": {
      "Description": "REQUIRED whatever dev or ops email list is appropriate for your project",
      "Type": "String",
      "AllowedPattern": "^[\\w-\\+]+(\\.[\\w]+)*@[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,})$",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid email address"
    },
```

I modified the allowed pattern to make it work with the # symbol in regex online https://regex101.com/r/uY6uH1/1. Eventhough it accepted here. When I tried the same in AWS CF, It doesn't work. How I can achieve this in AWS CF template.

Note : # may be changed to $,& anything in future. So I dont want to hard code all my special characters in the Regex

Answer (score 1):

Are you ensuring the escape characters in JSON are double escaped?

I was able to use the following template to successfully validate the email `#test-emailchec@example.com` used as the `contactemail` parameter

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "VPC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16"
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "contactemail": {
      "Description": "REQUIRED whatever dev or ops email list is appropriate for your project",
      "Type": "String",
      "AllowedPattern": "^[\\x20-\\x45]?[\\w-\\+]+(\\.[\\w]+)*@[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,})$",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid email address"
    }
  }
}
```